# Continuous integration/Testing Python on Heroku

Tags: python, unit-testing, heroku, continuous-integration

So I've been looking into ways to using Heroku for a small-scale personal project (Python Flask + MongoDB), however I can't seem to find much information on how to do simple continuos integration testing or simple unit testing on a Heroku staging instance. I feel that this would be necessary to make sure that everything will work in production, before actually making it public.

There doesn't seem to be much information on as to how I could achieve this. There are a couple of CI addons that would help, but they currently work only with Ruby/RoR ([tddium](https://www.tddium.com/), [Rails on Fire](https://www.railsonfire.com/)) and proper testing on Heroku seems like a problem that should already be solved by a number of people. [Buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) seem like a potential way to achieve what I need, but I'd rather use existing tools than re-invent the wheel myself.

So the question is, what are my options?

Comment: A new Heroku CI stack I'm looking to try out is [Strider CI](http://strider-cd.com/), and it looks like it has [python support](https://github.com/Strider-CD/strider-python). That said, haven't personally tried it, so can't attest to how well it works.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't advise on running your tests on Heroku, as the platform isn't designed to do this. It will probably take you much longer to get the Platform to work than simply using another hosted service. There are lots of other alternatives (e.g. Codeship where I am one of the founders).

At [Codeship](https://codeship.io) we are currently working on Python support which will be released soon.  MongoDB (as well as lots of other tools) is integrated nicely and works out of the box. We are also focusing very strongly on helping you deploy often and integrate that nicely, so you can work on your app and not your infrastructure.

Answer (score 4):

[CircleCi](https://circleci.com) has Python support! It also directly supports MongoDB. You'll be able to set it up very easily.

None of the hosted CI solutions, Circle included, run directly on Heroku. We (Circle - I'm a founder) have looked into it, but the way people write tests make this awkward (they're really designed to be run on the same machine). Heroku is also very slow and memory constrained, while the main goal of a CI system is to get results to you quickly.